# UMAT access violation in OpenCV -3.0.0 / OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

I have been trying to figure out simple subtract() and norm() operations on UMat variables. Since OpenCV 3.0.0, we have the T-API which gives the ease of access GPU/CPU power under OpenCL. 
I have confirmed that;

1. My systems's graphics INTEL HD 4600 has support for OpenCL 1.2
2. Since it was a bit clunky to figure out how to use specific devices in OpenCV, I now an environment variable as OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE = :GPU:0
3. I replaced some of the code with UMat and now I keep getting access violation errors.
4. Windows 8.1 (x64), VS2015 under VC++14. My application is x64 bit
5. OpenCV build with IPP,OPENCL options enabled. But I donot have Intel OpenCL SDK 1.2, just the drivers are available.

[image: OpenCL support]

[image: Environment variable]

[image: Stack Trace]
I have attached screen shots to ensure that I mean. You can clearly see from the stack trace for the error.

The code lines which I use for OpenCL support are;

```
 UMat result;
cv::subtract(FeatureVectorA.getUMat(ACCESS_READ),FeatureVectorB.getUMat(ACCESS_READ),result);
    auto r = cv::norm(result);
    result.release();
```

But this simple operation somehow seems to be broken. I donot know about OpenCL apart from that fact that it is a well followed standard by CPU/GPU/SoC manufacturers.

Any tips would be helpful.